# Mid-1980s 808x computer with 24-bit graphics

Tags: identify-this-computer, color-display

I remember seeing a computer with 24-bit graphics at a computer store in the mid-1980s.  It was not a normal PC with a high-end graphics board installed; the graphics came standard, possibly with three 8-bit graphics boards pre-installed.  In my memory this was a DEC Rainbow, but I looked that up, and that seems to have been an unremarkable business machine with just 1-bit/pixel.  Now I am thinking it may have been a high-end TI 808x machine aimed at the professional market (unlike the TI 99/4).

As I remember, this machine did not last very long.  There was very little software available supporting 24-bit graphics on PCs, and, while an MS-DOS machine, it was not considered a PC Clone.  Does anyone else remember such a thing?  What was it?

Comment: I checked my guess, the Mindset, but it did not have a 24-bit mode: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindset_(computer)

Comment: Mindset was my guess too. Perhaps [Atari Abaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Transputer_Workstation), which did support 24-bit? But that was not MSDOS.

Comment: I would be amazed if there was an exclusively MS-DOS computer that old that had 24-bit graphics. Was it something *nix based with a DOS card maybe?

Comment: @AlanB I'm not positive that it was not Unix, but pretty sure it was MSDOS. A review I half-remember reading based it's "not pc-compatible" conclusion on its inability to run Microsoft Flight Simulator.

Comment: Most likely a PC with TrueVision (AT&T) TARGA graphics card, used to run proprietary Paint applications (i.e. TARGA-PAINT), I believe, under MS-DOS.

Comment: The DEC Rainbow did not have 1 bit per pixel, but either 2 or 4. But it has a palette of 4096 colours though.